# Knife project not working (Blender 2.93.4)

Tags: edit-mode, knife-tool

1. Select the circle
2. Shift select the cube
3. Enter *Edit mode*
4. knife project

And it doesn't work

Has something changed? What I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: I can reproduce this and it looks like it might be a 2.93.4 regression.

Comment: Hi :). Selecting in Blender is a bit inconsistent. In viewport it's *Circle + shift + Cube*. In outliner it's *Cube + shift + circle*.

Comment: are they 2 separate objects?

Comment: Yes, they are separate objects

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 2.93.x you now need to select the object you want to cut the hole in.

Go into *Edit Mode* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> select the circle in the scene collection and then do *Knife Project*.